# Как передать параметр в функцию Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Как мне передать параметр в функцию класса?

**someclass.h**

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#define SOMECLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class SomeClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void setFilePath(QString fp) {
    if (file_path!=fp)
       file_path=fp;
}
    explicit SomeClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void func(QString file_path);


private:
  QString file_path;

};

#endif // SOMECLASS_H
```

**someclass.cpp**

```
#include "someclass.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QTextStream>

SomeClass::SomeClass(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{

}

void SomeClass::func(QString file_path)
{
    QStringList list;
    QString str;
    qDebug() << file_path;
}
```

Файл с которого запускаю поток:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
//    thread = new QThread();
    dil = new Dialog(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QThread *thread = new QThread;
    SomeClass *someClass = new SomeClass;
    someClass->moveToThread(thread);
    someClass->setFilePath(file_name);

    connect(thread, &QThread::started, someClass, &SomeClass::func);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater);

    thread->start();


}
```

Если я передаю параметр file_path, то у меня возникает ошибка:

**C:\Qt2\6.2.3\mingw_64\include\QtCore\qobject.h:230: ошибка: static assertion failed: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В тексте ошибки сказано: "Аргументы сигнала и слота не совместимы". Чтобы правильно вызвать функцию SomeClass::func вы должны передать ей параметр QString. Очевидно, что сигнал QThread::started() сделать этого не может (у него вообще нет параметров)
Вариант решения:

```
 connect(thread, &QThread::started, [this](){this->someClass->func("String argument");});
```

Comment: я пытался везде передавать параметры, но все равно выдавалась ошибка, можете пожалуйста показать куда передать параметр?

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: Смотрите, все равно ругается

Comment: [![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM84X.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM84X.png) Вот ругается все равно, скопировал что вы ввели

Comment: Ну гляньте, пожалуйста, сами как разрешать лямбдам захватывать переменные. Может, я чего не досмотрел в коде :)

Comment: Не понятно мне, все примеры с захватыми мне не знакомы ;(

Comment: connect(thread, &QThread::started, [this](){this->someClass->func("String argument");}); Вот так попробуйте

Comment: Спасибо, помогло
Измените свой ответ в теме на этот и я отмечу что ваш ответ помог.

Comment: Готово, поправил

Comment: connect(thread, &QThread::started, [someClass](){someClass->func("String argument");});

Comment: C:\QtTools\TestFirst\mainwindow.cpp:131: ошибка: variable 'file_name' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified

передаю в строке file_name, выдает это ;(

Comment: если передаю строковую переменную выдает ошибку,если просто строку все нормально 
Почему так;(

Comment: Не могу все таки передать переменную str, только строку
Саму переменную не получается

Answer (score 0):

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>

#include <someclass.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void postButtonClicked(QString path);

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QThread *thread = new QThread;
    SomeClass *someClass = new SomeClass;

    someClass->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(this, &MainWindow::postButtonClicked, someClass, &SomeClass::func);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater);

    thread->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    emit postButtonClicked("TEST PATH");
}
```

someclass.h

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#define SOMECLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class SomeClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SomeClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void func(QString path);

};

#endif // SOMECLASS_H
```

someclass.cpp

```
#include "someclass.h"
#include <QDebug>

SomeClass::SomeClass(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{

}

void SomeClass::func(QString path)
{
    qDebug() << "func()";
    qDebug() << path;
}
```

Comment: C:\QtTools\TestFirst\mainwindow.cpp:131: ошибка: variable 'file_name' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified передаю в строке file_name, выдает это ;( 
Ниже ответ помог, но для переменной не помогает

Comment: в моем коде переменной с именем file_name нет. Выложите сюда свой код